# Валидация поля с помощью JQuery как делать

Tags: jquery

[image: ошибочние собшение в виде красних полей]

```
<div id="forms">

   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" id="yourname"> 
   <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your Email" id="youremail"> 
   <div> 
     <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject"> 
   </div>
   <textarea id="textarea"> </textarea>
   <p id="button4">Send me a message</p>
</div>
```

---

JQuery

```
$("#button4").click(function() {


let yourname = $("#yourname").val()


let youremail = $("#youremail").val()


let subject = $("#subject").val()


let textarea = $("#textarea").val()


if (yourname=='' && youremail=='' && subject=='' && textarea=='') {
            $("#result").html("All fields are required")
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yourname=='' || youremail=='' || subject=='' || textarea=='') {
```